# XNA 4.0 Moving Player left and right doesnt work,why?

Tags: c#, xna

I followed the Tutorials of Oyyou91 on YouTube, to make a little tile based Jump and Run Game.
However, everytime i tried to move the player left or right, he just wont move. He only moves left or Right, when hes Jumping. After that, i completly redid everything and did it the same way he (Oyyou91) did, and the player still wont move when hes standing on the ground.
Here is the static TileCollider class:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace XJump
{
    public static class TileCollider
    {
        public static bool TouchesTop(Rectangle rect1, Rectangle rect2)
        {
            if ((rect1.Bottom >= rect2.Top - 1) && (rect1.Bottom <= rect2.Top + (rect2.Height / 2))&&
                (rect1.Right >= rect2.Left + rect2.Width / 5)&&(rect1.Left <= rect2.Right - rect2.Width / 5))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public static bool TouchesBottom(Rectangle rect1, Rectangle rect2)
        {
            if ((rect1.Top <= rect2.Bottom +(rect2.Height / 5))&&
                (rect1.Top >= rect2.Bottom -1)&&
                (rect1.Right >= rect2.Left + (rect2.Width / 5))&&
                (rect1.Left <= rect2.Right - (rect2.Width / 2)))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public static bool TouchesLeft(Rectangle rect1, Rectangle rect2)
        {
            if ((rect1.Right <= rect2.Right)&&
                (rect1.Right >= rect2.Left -5)&&
                (rect1.Top >= rect2.Bottom - (rect2.Width / 4))&&
                (rect1.Bottom <= rect2.Top + (rect2.Width / 4)))
            {
                return true;

            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public static bool TouchesRight(Rectangle rect1, Rectangle rect2)
        {
            if ((rect1.Left >= rect2.Left)&&
                (rect1.Left <= rect2.Right + 5)&&
                (rect1.Top >= rect2.Bottom - (rect2.Width / 4))&&
                (rect1.Bottom <= rect2.Top + (rect2.Width / 4)))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            } 
        }




    }
}
```

and here is my Player class:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using XJump.Map;
using XJump.Tiles;

namespace XJump.Entities
{
    class Player
    {
        private Texture2D texture;
        private Rectangle rectangle;

        private float VelocityY;
        private float VelocityX;
        private bool HasJumped = false;

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch sb)
        {
            sb.Draw(texture, rectangle, Color.White);
        }
        private void Update()
        {
            VelocityX = 0;
            if (VelocityY < 10)
            {
                VelocityY += 1;
            }

            KeyboardState ks = Keyboard.GetState();
            MouseState ms = Mouse.GetState();

            Collision();
            Input(ks, ms);


            rectangle.X += (int)VelocityX;
            rectangle.Y += (int)VelocityY;


        }
        private void Input(KeyboardState ks, MouseState ms)
        {

            if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            {
                VelocityX = -10;
            }
            if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            {
                VelocityX = 10;
            }
            if(ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            {
                if(!HasJumped)
                {
                    VelocityY -= 15f;
                    rectangle.Y -= 5;
                    HasJumped = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                VelocityX = 0;
            }

            Rectangle msr = new Rectangle(ms.X, ms.Y, 1, 1);
            if(msr.Intersects(this.rectangle)&&ms.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                VelocityY = 0f;
                VelocityX = 0f;

                rectangle.X = msr.X;
                rectangle.Y = msr.Y;
            }

            }



        private void Collision()
        {
            foreach (CollisionTile tile in TileMap.TilesRear)
            {

                if(TileCollider.TouchesTop(this.rectangle, tile.rect))
                {
                    VelocityY = 0;
                    HasJumped = false;
                }
                if (TileCollider.TouchesBottom(this.rectangle, tile.rect))
                {
                    VelocityY += 5;
                }
                if (TileCollider.TouchesLeft(this.rectangle, tile.rect))
                {
                    VelocityX = 0;
                }
                if (TileCollider.TouchesRight(this.rectangle, tile.rect))
                {
                    VelocityX = 0;
                }


            }


        }
        public Player(int PosX, int PosY)
        {
            texture = GlobalContainer.TileSet[3];
            rectangle = new Rectangle(PosX, PosY, texture.Width, texture.Height);

            TileMap.DrawingEntities += this.Draw;
            TileMap.Updating += this.Update;
        }

    }
}
```

As i already Said, the player only moves left and Right when in air(not touching any Tile). I still cant figure out the problem. Please help me.

Comment: Minor tip: instead of doing `if(x) return true; else return false;`, just do `return x;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
 {
    if(!HasJumped)
    {
        VelocityY -= 15f;
        rectangle.Y -= 5;
        HasJumped = true;
    }
  }
  else
  {
     VelocityX = 0;  <---- Dont do this
  }
```

You reset your `VelocityX`  back to 0

You may want (Dont move left or right while jumping)

```
 if(ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
 {
    if(!HasJumped)
    {
        VelocityY -= 15f;
        rectangle.Y -= 5;
        HasJumped = true;
    }
     else
    {
        VelocityX = 0; 
    }
}
```

Comment: @Daniel Wanner, if this answers your question, you should mark it as so. For one thing, this will help others who have the same problem as you did.

Answer (score 0):

try to add a Position vector2 variable, so this will keep track of the location of the player, whilst the velocity variable will keep track of the speed in which the player is moving in a given direction, e.g. VelocityY = at what speed is the player's Y position changing...

Hope this helps... GL